# javascript calls function and then destroys function output

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a page with two submit buttons, each of which calls a different program.  In either case, I need to validate the form that is being submitted.  Here is the form tag:

```
<form name    = "let2form" 
  id          = "let2form"
  method      = "post" 
  action      = ""       
  onkeypress  = "return event.keyCode != 13;">
```

and the javascript call:

```
<input type  = "Submit"
         id    = "showbut" 
         class = "submitbut"                        
         style = "width: 120px; height:50px;font-family:comic sans ms;font-size: 16px;"
         value     = "show #mtype#s"
         onclick   = "bbsubmit('let3-1.cfm', 'let2form','0','tip_title')">
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function bbsubmit(target,xsource, sortlen, msg) {
  aret = subpers2(sortlen,msg);
  if(aret == true) {
  document.getElementById(xsource).action = target;}
}
```

The function subpers2 is being called correctly, and is returning the correct true or false.  It is also outputting an error message when there is a problem.

[image: error message showing]

When it returns to the function bbsubmit, the error message vanishes from the user's screen.

[image: error message not showing]

which of course is not what I want.

If I knew what was causing this I would fix it.  I suspect it may be some kind of scope problem, but I still don't know what to do.  Can someone explain what is going on and how to fix it.

Comment: When you press submit, you are probably reloading the page, you probably want to use `event.preventDefault()`. `onclick   = "bbsubmit(event, 'let3-1.cfm', 'let2form','0','tip_title')` then `function bbsubmit(event,target,xsource, sortlen, msg){event.preventDefault() /*The rest*/}`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - that won't work in all browsers, since `event` is a microsoft non-standard invention (which chrum picked up years ago, and firefox much more recently, maybe not released yet) - I don't understand why people insist on using `form` for something that is never submitted as such :p

Comment: If you're not redirecting anywhere, I would suggest just dropping the form tag

Comment: Jaromanda and Abana, I'm using a form because I need to submit it to the program let3b_1.cfm.  So I don't understand your comments about not using a form.  How else am I supposed to get to the target page?

Comment: GetOffMyLawn, I need the form to be submitted if there are no errors, and for it not to submit if there are errors.  If I have just one submit button and use the action in the form itself, it will not submit if there are errors.  If I get back to bbsubmit from the call to subpers2 and there are errors, there will be no submit, so the page shouldn't be reloading.